# why is array undefined in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, undefined

when executing the following code firebug tells me: msj[0] is undefined what is the problem?

What I want to do is that every time it receives a response after every run, catch it in the array after calling msg to generate a single alert to show me all the answers together...

I don't understand why me show undefined if the array has data, in this case has three data..

```
var msj = [];

for (var a = document.querySelectorAll('table.inventory tbody tr'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {
    // get inventory row cells
    cells = a[i].querySelectorAll('span:last-child');
    // buscar la selecion del concepto
    var opciones = cells[0].querySelectorAll('option:checked');
    var value_concept = opciones[0].value;
    // set price as cell[2] * cell[3]
    var Uno = value_concept;
    var Dos = cells[1].innerHTML ;
    var Tres = parseFloatHTML(cells[2]);
    var Cuatro = parseFloatHTML(cells[3]);
    var Cinco = parseFloatHTML(cells[4]);

    var id_fac = id_fac_select;
    var valor_fac = costo_fac_select.split(".");
    var valor_fact = valor_fac[0];
    var valor_recibo = Cinco;

    $.ajax({
        url:"js.php",
        cache:false,
        type:"POST",
        data:{concepto:Uno,descripcion:Dos,valor_total:Tres,valor_pagado:Cuatro,valor_f:valor_fact,saldo_pendiente:valor_recibo,numero_factura:id_fac,id_estudiante:id_student},
        success:function(result)
        {   
            msj.push(result);               
        }
        });

}
console.log(msj);
alert(msj[0]);
```

Comment: It doesn't really look like you're iterating at all with that strange for loop. Have you looked at examples on the web on how to write a for loop ?

Comment: And ajax is **asynchronous** !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing `undefined` in the `alert()` because `msj` doesn't have data ***yet***.  Your code that populates `msj` is not called until the browser receives a response from the server, but your `alert(msg[0])` code is called immediately.

If you are seeing data in the console from your `console.log(msj)`, this is because the console doesn't evaluate objects until you expand them.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/361684).  Try changing your console.log to something like one of these:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(msj));
console.log(msj.length);
console.log(msj.join(","));
```

**Edit:**  It sounds like you want to gather all of the responses, and then do something once you've received all of them.  In your `success` handler, after you have added the result to `msj`, check the `length` to see if you've received all of them.  When all of the responses have been received, `msj.length` should be the same as `a.length`:

```
success: function (result) {   
    msj.push(result);
    if (msj.length == a.length) {
        // All responses have been received. Ready to use msj!
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answers, but did not work... when change async in false yes work, but it is a bad practice... i don't know as i do.... help me please.

Comment: @Al3mor, try moving the `console` and `alert` inside the `success` function. That way they will not be called until there's something in `msj`.

Comment: of this mode works, but generate message each time through the sentence for... what I need is to generate all the answers in a single alert and thought I could do this by storing the data in an array, but does not work... you know if i can do it otherwise?

Comment: @gilly3 Is running correctly... thank you very much... // No te imaginas lo agradecida que estoy... Muchisimas Gracias por toda tu ayuda.... un abrazo desde Colombia!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `console` and `alert` calls into the success function.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"js.php",
    cache:false,
    type:"POST",
    data:{concepto:Uno,descripcion:Dos,valor_total:Tres,valor_pagado:Cuatro,valor_f:valor_fact,saldo_pendiente:valor_recibo,numero_factura:id_fac,id_estudiante:id_student},
    success:function(result)
    {   
        msj.push(result);               
        console.log(msj);
        alert(msj[0]);        }
    });
```

Comment: of this mode works, but generate message each time through the sentence for... what I need is to generate all the answers in a single alert and thought I could do this by storing the data in an array, but does not work... you know if i can do it otherwise?